# Flipped image with front camera

Tags: android, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova 3.5.0 's camera api. When i take pictures using the front camera the image is flipped for android. I have set the `correctOrientation` to `true` but it doesn't help. After some reading i came across that Android plugin doesn't copy the EXIF tags. How to correct this and prevent the image from flipping using the front camera.